# Notification about math jax for new users

Tags: discussion, feature-request, mathjax, editing, new-users

I saw a problem which is common for new users who are using math jax. although they can write formula for example it is not hard to guess to show $x^2$ you should write `x^2` but most of them don't know they should enclose their formulas with dollar symbol. So as I said it is a common problem for most new users. it happened to me too I could right click on formulas that was written by other users and select "Show Math As>Math ML Code" and copy and paste them to understand how they work but it really take a lot of time (maybe a week) for me to realize I should put them between $$.

So my suggestion is showing a notification for new users when they are writing formulas and says "You should enclose your formulas with dollar  signs in order to display like `$x^3$`" or something like that. it can really help them.

Comment: I believe the hope is that you, and the new users have been linked to https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference at some point

Comment: +1 for bringing this. Perhaps the use of MathJax when writting math should be mentioned on the Tour. How/where did you learn to use $$?

Comment: @vino I don't remember, that I think maybe some user mentioned it to me or I finally saw the question  on Calvin Khor comment. but I had a hard time to find it out!

Comment: I normally link to the [brief introduction to typeset mathematical notation](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).  It includes a link to the more comprehensive resource linked by @CalvinKhor.

Comment: You might support this feature request - posted not too long ago by @Verónica: [Adding the link of the MathJax tutorial in the Tour and/or the sidebar displayed when asking a question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33196).